# Long load times due to "Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When running my unity game on android, it now takes an extremely long time to load new scenes.

I looked at the logcat while the game was running, and I see this entry 1000's of times:
Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)

It finally stops after multiple minutes depending on how complex the previous scene was.

This started happening when I updated to the latest version of Unity. No code changed, and before the update, the scenes all loaded instantly on android, even on low end devices.

I'm in desperate need of help.
Is there some way to simply unload the entire scene all at once? It seems that this used to be the case.

Comment: This could be a Unity bug, what version were you on before?

Comment: It was 5.5.x I don't know the exact previous version.

Comment: 5.5.2 maybe? I know I've been having some issues in my own development with bugs introduced by 5.6.1 (or at least, one *confirmed* bug and a second that I reported yesterday).